# Apache reverts PHP version after inactivity

Tags: apache2, apache2.4

I am using a2dismod en a2enmod to switch PHP versions. Because I work on a lot of projects that require different PHP versions. But now, whenever I change from 7.0 to 7.2 it changes back after a little time when I'm not using Apache (loading pages, clicking on things, ect)

Using

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2018-06-07T19:43:03
```

Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had puppit installed, and it was changing the version back every 30 minutes.
Looked like inactivity but wasn't. Oops!